# D3, dates on the x axis, data the width of a date

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am visualizing data by date.  I want something a bit like this:

[image]

The point is that I want to draw rectangles that are the width of the days. Here's how I draw rectangles:

```
svg.selectAll(".my_class")
.data(my_data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr({
    "width": function(d) { return x_scale.rangeBand(); },
    "height": function(d) { return h_scale(d.end - d.start); },
    "x": function(d) { return x_scale(new Date(d.date)); },
    "y": function(d) { return y_scale(d.end); },
    "class": function(d) { return d.device; }
});
```

The problem is that in order to get the right width, I ended up declaring my x_scale thus

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(my_data.map(function (d) { return new Date(d.date); }))
.rangeRoundBands([0, image_width]);
```

when I surely should have used `d3.time.scale()` instead.  (Note the non-gaps after 2, 7, and 12 Feb.)  The problem is that I don't see a way to specify the rectangle widths using `d3.time.scale()`.

A work-around is to generate zero-height rectangles on the back end for every day in the period.  This isn't *that* hideous, but I feel I should be able to do better.  In addition, I'd lose niceties like `.ticks(d3.time.weeks, 1)` and have to spin them myself.

Any pointers?

Comment: You can get the width of a single day from a time scale as well, can't you? Just get the position of a date and subtract the position of a date one day earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the simplest solution I found was to use an ordinal scale and provide (sometimes empty) elements for each date in the range.